# How to increase size allocated to a user

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

I am using dual boot with Ubuntu / Windows.

I am currently working under Ubuntu and trying to download some files to my desktop. The problem is that the download fails due to insufficient space.

When I run the disk usage analyzer, I see the following:

Total filesystem capacity: **115.2 GB** (used : 32.3 GB available: 82.9 GB)

However, the size allocated to my user (/home/fshelly/) appears to be only 9.9 GB which exceeds the amount of the files that I'd like to download.

Is there any way to increase the 9.9 GB so that I can download without any problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your home directory has its own partition. You can either:

1. resize the partition using gparted, just boot ubuntu live cd (dangerous)
2. make a copy of your home folder on your root partition then disable the home mount in /etc/fstab

The output of this terminal command will show you usage/free space for each mount on your install.

`df -h`

gparted is a GUI program and simple to use but it is dangerous because you can kill partitions and filesystems.

If you use choice 2 then use the tar command to make the copy of your home filesystem. Your original home device will remain, it just won't be mounted (won't be accessible).

This link looks like a good tar example.

`http://www.aboutdebian.com/tar-backup.htm`

however you will want to backup and restore just the /home folder.

also look at the mount command in terminal.

`man mount`

here is a list of steps that come to mind.

become root `sudo -i`

go to root folder `cd /`

edit: forgot tar -p for preserve.

backup `tar -zpcvf /home-backup.tar.gz /home`

unmount home `umount /home` or `umount /home/<yourname>`

restore `tar -zpxvf /home-backup.tar.gz`

comment out the home mount in fstab `gedit /etc/fstab`

look for something like ...

`# /home/myname was on /dev/sdb2 during installation`
`UUID=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 /home/myname   ext4    defaults        0       2`

and comment it out using the hash `#` char

`# /home/myname was on /dev/sdb2 during installation`
`# UUID=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 /home/myname   ext4    defaults        0       2`

finally reboot.